# Locate Scheduled Jobs on OS X Server - Cron Job?

Tags: cron, osx-snow-leopard, launchd, osx-server

Currently migrating from an old OS X server to a new IBM setup that uses Red Hat Enterprise. The old system ran a PHP script on a schedule (7:30 each morning) to get files from an FTP server.

My problem: I can't find out how it was scheduled. I've checked for Cron Jobs but there is nothing there (using terminal `$ chrontab -l`).

**What are other common schedulers available for OS X/BSD?** I've also checked launchd but that doesn't appear to be the scheduler either.

Server running:

```
OS X Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8
```